# Matplotlib: 'savefig' throw TypeError when 'linewidths' property is set

Tags: matplotlib

When the 'linewidths' property is set, calling 'savefig' throws 'TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type'. Here is a MWE:

```
# Create sample data.
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = 10.0 * (2*X - Y)
# Plot sample data.
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, colors = 'black', linewidths = '1') 
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

It is not a problem with the figure rendering (calling 'plt.show()' works fine). If the linewidths property is not set, e.g. changing the second last line to

```
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, colors = 'black')
```

'savefig' works as intended. Is this a bug or have i missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, since the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contour) for `plt.contour()` specifies that `linewidths` should be a [ `None` | number | tuple of numbers ] while you provide a number as a `string`.

Here is my output with your code (I am using `matplotlib 1.4.3`).

```
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.4.3'
```

Your code 'works' under Python 2.7 but the `linewidths` parameter is effectively ignored, producing plots that look like this, regardless of the value (this was with `linewidths='10'`.

[image: linewidths as a string]

In contrast on Python 3.4 I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Setting `linewidths` to an `int` (or a `float`) as follows produces the correct output and works on both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4. Again, this is with it set to `10`:

```
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, colors = 'black', linewidths = 10)
```

[image: linewidth as an int]